# Native client app must access a mysql server side DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, client-side

I have a website with a mysql DB and I'm going to create a native app (probably in C#/WPF) which must access this DB.

Is it more secure and efficient to directly access this DB (and so keep the access information in the client app) or to create a PHP API ?

Thank you, Sébastien

Comment: You mean, like, public, unfettered, free-for-all, direct, raw, easily sniffable access to the database over the web? What could possibly go wrong‽

Comment: How can it be sniffable if I use HTTPS ?

Comment: It doesn't need to be sniffed out of the air if the attacker has the binary which contains the access credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a PHP API. If you connected directly, people could gain direct access to your mysql  basically giving them full power.

Comment: This depends, of course, on whether the client application would connect as a database user who only has access to stored procedures that implement proper application-level authentication and authorization.

Comment: It would still give enough access to spam the DB, and possibly gain confidential information.

Comment: Sure, and there is no possibility to spam the PHP interface or break its security, right?  I'm not arguing that a PHP layer won't be a good thing, only that you can implement a proper layer in the database itself; layers external to the DB are not a panacea for security.

Comment: I'll have full power for my app methods, but the access information are encapsulated in the code, so normally no one can see these information ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: @cdhowie The PHP layer will have much more security and will beable to prevent things like that.
At Sebastien A hex editor/decompiler will reveal it.

Comment: Sebastian: If someone can sniff the network or just decompile the code, they can retrieve the database credentials.  They can then connect using a MySQL client, provide those credentials, and then issue whatever queries they please.

Comment: @Someguynamedpie: The PHP layer does not have more security just by virtue of being written in PHP.  Just because you don't know how to implement proper security at the database level does not mean that it cannot be done.

Comment: Tell me how now, that the mysql level database will be able to prevent spam attacks, confidential information leaks, etc for something that needs rw access

Comment: Stored procedures (and a DB user restricted to only using those procedures).  The procedures would require application-level credentials, which ensures that one user cannot mess with data he shouldn't have access to just by making a raw database connection -- the only things he can do are call stored procedures, and if those procedures require valid application credentials to operate, he is no better off.  Spam attacks can and should be dealt with at the edge router using stateful packet inspection.

Comment: PHP won't solve spam attacks against the HTTPD either.  Ultimately, you need an edge router to deal with spam/DoS style attacks.  Middleware is not going to solve those attacks.  Further, a spam attack on stored procedures using incorrect application credentials will not actually have much impact on the DB server, since it will be rejecting most requests.  If the credentials are correct, then an audit trail can be used to determine the misbehaving user and they can be properly disciplined.

Comment: Never meant DOS attacks, just spamming and filling up the DB

Comment: If a user is filling up the DB, that's a behavioral issue that needs to be resolved with discipline or banning.  A PHP layer isn't going to solve that problem either.

Comment: Banning won't solve having the login info and being able to log in(from other computers if it gets an IP ban). PHP can limit attacks like that

Comment: @Someguynamedpie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2654/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-someguynamedpie)

Comment: So if I use an API, there is approximately the same problem. I want my app the be the only one which can access these information, so I need a private API key but this key must be stored in the code and so the user can decompile the code and so...

Comment: Not approximately, a much smaller chance. I'd stick with the PHP method.

Comment: @Sebastian: If your code is running on the user's machine, the user can change its behavior in some way or another.  It's important to properly secure your server-side layer, whether that be a PHP API or stored procedures.  Never assume that data originating from machines out of your control can be trusted.

Comment: @cdhowie I was assuming based on his wording that it would be a client application

Comment: Where do I indicate that it's not a client application?  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say.

Comment: If your code is running on the user's machine. It doesn't matter though, we best stop here.

Comment: @cdhowie: yes, but if the private API key is stolen from my client app code, how can I secure the server side ? I can't detect the calling app (the HTTP header can be modified). So I do not have any good solution (just a best solution) and the only thing I can do is hoping no one can decompile my API private key ?

Comment: Require all users to have credentials to use the application, and then verify those credentials on each request.

Comment: I understand that (this is the user private key), but what I want is an app private key (which must be stored in the app). This app private key provide access to specific api methods (my app must be the only one which can access these methods) and other apps accessing my api can't implement these api methods. So if someone steal my api private key he can build an app with all these specific methods.

Comment: You won't need one, just do all the auth stuff on the PHP side

Comment: @Someguynamedpie: And how can I now if this is not an app build by an other user ?

Comment: You don't need to know. Just do some authentication, and request something like ?username=asd&password=bsd that echos a session that can be used to do DB things

Comment: This is not what I want. I said I know all the stuffs about user private key an auth. What I want is to provide two kinds of API: a public (which nevertheless need sometimes a user auth) and a private one. The public is open to every developers and the private one must only be used by my own app (this private api provide advanced access to the DB data).